# ParameterCache.SetParameters is not populating the parameters

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle11g, enterprise-library, oracle19c

We have upgraded the Oracle client 19 to 11 and after that our application is stopped working and throwing error "An OracleParameter with parameterName 'parametername' is not contained by this OracleParameterCollection."

After debugging I found issue in below lines:

```
command = database.GetStoredProcCommand("procedure name");
parameterCache.SetParameters(command, database); // this line doesn't populate the data
Database.SetParameterValue(command, "columnName", "columnValue"); // throws error
```

Above lines was working fine with Oracle client 11 but throws error with Oracle client 19. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using the dinosaurian Enterprise Library in 2021? All of its useful features were incorporated into ADO.NET 2.0 16 years ago. Few people even remember what it was and those that do would never use it again. Just create and (re)use an OracleCommand. In those 16 years ADO.NET itself has changed a lot and EntLib's DAAB probably no longer works with the current versions. Few people remember what this was, and those that do wouldn't use EntLib at all

Comment: This application was written long time back and now I am supporting this application. Not sure if client will be agree to rewrite the entire data layer. BTW Thank you for your response.